# Symlink multiple files RAMdisk

Tags: 16.04

I want had some files with same name and extension, from different folders at my /dev/md3 in my RAMdisk symlink files to RAMdisk and backup to hdd.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to create symlinks in your RAM disk that point to files on your actual disk? Yes, that is possible if the symlinks have either different names or are located in different subdirectories in the RAM disk.

Answer (score 1):

"Symlinks" (AKA "Soft links") aren't the best tool for this. There's a tool, called `hardlink` (Provided by: `hardlink_0.3.0build1_amd64`) designed to "`Link multiple copies of a file`"